# Android API level 9 Notification with 2 or 3 buttons in notification drawer

Tags: android

Is it possible to create notification with few buttons in notification  drawer, which execute different tasks? 
android:minSdkVersion="9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expandable notifications with buttons etc. are only supported Jelly Bean onwards. It is possible to integrate them when targeting a minimum of API 9, but you will need to use runtime checks to see if you're on a Jelly Bean device or not. If you are, you can display an actionable notification, and if you aren't you can default back to the normal notification.